# How to make email validation in android?

Tags: android

I have an edit text and have implemented some validation for this but when I type 
"RRRR@RRRRFF.cOM" it will accept that value.How can I do that

code:-

```
/*validation for email*/
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {// validation for email Id
    String emailPattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: Aren't e-mail's CaSe InSenSiTiVe?

Comment: any particular reason not to use `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email Address Validation in Android on EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947620/email-address-validation-in-android-on-edittext)

Comment: *RRRR@RRRRFF.cOM* is a valid email.

Comment: thats what I am asking but when I add this value app does not show error

Comment: because its is valid. You want to show error when it is valid??

Comment: but how is it valid cOM is a domain

Comment: no but c small and OM big is a valid domain

Comment: please refer [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001081.htm)

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666782/are-idn-domain-names-case-sensitive

Comment: Is cOM is valid domain

Comment: yes.. But you can accept the value in lowercase from the `EditText` to avoid this confusion

Comment: Normally the email id are accepted in lowercases to avoid this kind of confusions

Comment: That *is* a valid email address. Domain names are case-insensitive. Email addresses are actually case-insensitive, per the RFC, but most providers fold all case variants into one inbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
Pattern.compile(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.toString()).matcher(textView.getText().toString()).matches()
```

Comment: not an answer. it will still return true in the above case

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
 if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress.getText().toString()).matches()) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, getString(R.string.plzenter_valid_email), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. its works like a charm

```
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;

    }
    return isValid;
```