# How can I retrieve the sub domain in a servlet? Does spring have any helpers

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I first want to know if there is a built-in way of getting a subdomain from a url using pure servlets?

And then if spring has any helpers?

So my urls would be like:

```
jonskeet.stackoverflow.com
```

Where JonSkeet is the subdomain.

I will create a filter that will load a object based on the subdomain value.

BTW, when creating a filter, is there a way to order the filters to make sure they all fire in a specific order?

Comment: Misspelled Jon Skeet's name there buddy, tisk tisk!

Comment: +1 if you wondered if SO has really created a Jon Skeet sub-domain and tried to visit http://jonskeet.stackoverflow.com

Comment: No, I don't think you can go further than obtaining the URL and then splitting the String yourself. BTW, you should not put more than one question, particularly when your question about filters can be answered quickly with a Google search.

Comment: wow that is surprising, I was certain there would be something.

Answer (score 8):

I doubt there is a special API for this. But you can get it from HttpRequest using `request.getServerName().split("\\.")[0]`. It seems it is easy enough.

Limitation is that you cannot support "subdomain" that contains dot characters, e.g. `jon.skeet.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: Ah, sub-domains cannot **really** contain dots, see for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111881/what-are-the-allowed-characters-in-a-sub-domain

Comment: In other word: the dot is not part of the sub-domain, it's a separator for the textual portions of the domain name.

Comment: getServerName() returns also www, so it will fail, sooner or later

Comment: But for practical purposes, "www" is also a subdomain.

Comment: @Renascienza, FYI, not all domains start with 'www'

Comment: @AlexR, of course not. But "www" is a *valid* subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava.

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
 compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
 ...
}
```

Java:

```
    private String getSubdomain(HttpServletRequest req) {

        String site = req.getServerName();

        String domain = InternetDomainName.from(site).topPrivateDomain().toString();
        String subDomain = site.replaceAll(domain, "");
        subDomain = subDomain.substring(0, subDomain.length() - 1);

        return subDomain;
}
```

So, "jon.skeet.stackoverflow.com" will return "jon.skeet".