# PHP cURL doesn't work with - in subdomains

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that I'm trying to get the contents of a page. The code im using is below

```
$url = "http://test.tumblr.com";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$txt = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "$txt";
```

It works fine for me as it is now. The problem I'm having is, if I change the string URL to

`$url = "http://-test.tumblr.com";` or `$url = "http://test-.tumblr.com";`

It will not work. I understand that -test.example.com or test-.example.com is not a valid hostnames but with Tumblr they do exists. Is there a work around for this?

I even tried creating a header redirect on another php file so cURL would be first getting a valid hostname but works the same way.

Thank you

Comment: are you sure they exist ?

Comment: You can try file_get_contents if you just have to grab contents

Comment: @njzk2 yes they both exists.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I have already tried that also, same results. :)

Comment: They both 404 for me. Are you sure they exist?

Comment: @PeterKelly when you visit them they do exists. You're experiencing the same problem I'm having.

Comment: No I simply browsed to them in Firefox, they 404.

Comment: @PeterKelly I'm using chrome. Here is another URL `http://-racing-heart-.tumblr.com` example only I have no affiliations to that URL.

Comment: i'm using chrome and I can't get to this url you gave.

Comment: @njzk2 That's strange, they do work for me fine. Must be a issue with Tumblr.

Comment: Probably Tumblr catches this with a wildcard DNS entry [SO Question: Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php).

Answer (score 0):

### Domain Names with hyphens

As you can see in a previous question about [the allowed characters in a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111947/823963), `-` is not a valid character to start or end a subdomain with. So this is actually correct behavior.
The same problem was reported over the `curl` [mailing list](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2007-06/0069.html) some time ago but since `curl` follows the standard, there is actually nothing to change on their site.

Most likely tumblr knows about this and therefore offers some alternative address leading to the same site.

### Possible workaround

However you could try using `nslookup` to manually lookup the IP and then send your request directly to this IP (and manually setting the hostname to the correct value). I didn't try this out, but it seems as if `nslookup` is capable to resolve *malformatted* domain names that start or end in a hyphen.

### curl

Additionally you should know, that the php `curl` function should be a direct interface to the  `curl` command line tool and therefore, if you would encounter special behavior it would most likely be due to the logic in the `curl` command line tool and not the php function.

Comment: They do not offer any work around except to see if the blog exists. I'm trying to find a work around. :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a possible workaround. I didn't try it out but I think it could work.