# Regex to match all subdomains of a matched domains

Tags: java, regex

I have a Regex to match a subdomains of a web page like below

```
 "^https://[^/?]+\\.(sub1|sub2\\.)domain\\.com"
```

What would be the regex to accept any sub domain of domain.com.

Edit:

My question was incomplete, my regex was to accept only

```
 https:[any number of sub domain s ].sub1domain.com
```

or

```
 https://[any number of sub domain s ].sub2domain.com
```

Sorry for posting incomplete question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
https?://([a-z0-9]+[.])*sub[12]domain[.]com
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xBWNJHZqGrLdyLYE)
- Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36lo6)

Comment: In this way (as your demo tested) the URL https://sub1.sub2.sub1domain.com return *sub2*, while I suppose he desire *sub1.sub2*.

Comment: @marianoc84 I don't get it... What do you mean by *"return"*?

Comment: @sp00m Possibly "captured in $1".

Comment: Nice. Keep in mind: `-` is also allowed in subdomain and its better to escape `/`, and it should start with letter not number

Comment: @chefarov From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111947/1225328, it looks like it does can start with a number. I don't see why it's better to escape `/`, it totally depends on your language/engine. Good point about `-` though: if needed, one could use `([a-z0-9]+(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?[.])*` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
(http|https)://(.*).domain.com
```

At this point second tag (i.e. `\2` or `$2` variable) is what you need. Notice, this regex doesn't validate URL.

Proof: https://www.debuggex.com/r/3KYGmAnlnBq3C_fT

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please look at my question update

Comment: Check now, and let me know!

Comment: IMPORTANT: Only use this one if you can always trust the source. This answer insecurely matches something like `"https://totally.bad.url.com/fake/out.domain.com/"`, which could be used for phishing depending on how you're displaying it. The accepted answer does not have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that don't want the subdomains to differ simply by a number. Use this regex:

```
(^https:\/\/(?:[\w\-\_]+\.)+(?:subdomain1|subdomain2).com)
```

The single capture group is the full URL. Simply replace subdomain1 and subdomain2 with your actual subdomains.

I tested this on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the sub domains contain only numbers and lowercase letters and you do not want to accept sub subdomains:

```
[0-9a-z]*\.domain\.com
```

update:

```
https://.*\.sub[1|2]domain\.com
```

matches

```
https://sub1.sub2.sub1domain.com 
https://sub1.sub1domain.com
```

but not

```
https://sub1domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please look at my question update

Answer (score 2):

You would use

```
"^https://[^/?]+\\.([^.]+)\\.domain\\.com"
```

which boils down to matching

```
"[^.]+"
```

for any subdomain. will match only the last part of the subdomain (www.xxx.domain.com will capture "xxx" in group 1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please look at my question update

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://([^.]+\\.)+sub[12]domain.com`. A great place for testing out regexes with minimal setup pain is [RegexPlanet](http://regexplanet.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Regex that match any number of subdomains also allowing IDN domains and check the limit of 63 or less characters. And it check that the - is not at first or last position.

```
https?://([a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9])?[.])*sub[12][.]domain[.]com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The forward slashes // at the start need to be escaped for proper regular expression, so correct is:

```
https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*sub[12]domain[.]com
```