# Match only links that contain only second level domains from a list of URLs

Tags: regex

I am trying to filter a list of links to match only those which are only a second level domain

Success:

```
https://www.thingisawesome.anything
https://thingisawesome.anything
http://www.thingisawesome.anything
http://thingisawesome.anything
http://thingisawesome.anything/
https://www.thingisawesome.anything/
```

Failure:

```
http://thingisawesome.ventures/index.html
https://subdomain.geocities.com/
https://www.twitter.com/8288hs98ff
```

This got me close:

`(http)s?(:\/\/)(w*)(\.?)(\w*)(.)(\w*)(\/?)`

But it would not reject the ones to fail, only match part of it.

Comment: [`anything`, `ventures`, and `com` are TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) in your examples. Am I correct in understanding that you want to match URLs that have only the `http` or `https` scheme, any second-level domain, and an optional subdomain of `www`?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I am not looking for TLDs, but instead a link that has only a second level domain, that is http or https.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples (which aren’t matching TLDs), which show newline-separated lists of URLs (no [unencoded IDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)), and assuming the capture groups in your attempt aren’t used later, you want to match (in multiline mode):

- the start of the line
- `http`
- an optional `s`
- `://`
- an optional `www.`
- the 2LD and TLD, [which can consist of letters, numbers, and hyphens (but not in the initial position)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111947/8492116)
- an optional slash
- the end of the line

Putting that together gives us:

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?$
```

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/2UNGxn/2)

Comment: Updated the regex. `\w` is too permissive for domain names.