# For an email address, match either a domain or a domain with a subdomain?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression which will work on an email. I need to match that an email is either from a certain domain or from a certain domain and subdomain. A domain must be matched precisely.

I have this:

```
@.*\.?somedomain\.com$
```

Yes, this will match:

```
  fdsafd@a1.somedomain.com
  fdsafd@somedomain.com
  fdsafd@aabbddjjj.somedomain.com
```

which is what I need. However, it'll also a domain which contains `somedomain.com` as a part in it, and this isn't  what I want:

fdsafd@partsomedomain.com

I want the domain `somedomain.com` to be matched precisely.

How to fix it?

Comment: You need to make the whole subdomain optional, not just the dot. Instead of `.*\.?`, use something like `(?:.*\.)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JakOtR/1)). Moreover, you probably should replace the `.*` part with something [more strict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7111881/8967612).

Comment: @41686d6564 I was going with another solution, realised I was wrong and now I've posted an answer which is basically your comment. Tell me if you post it as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @41686d6564 why is `?:` needed?

Comment: @Aaron That's fine. It doesn't matter who posted the answer as long as the OP got their problem solved :)

Comment: @kosmosu It's called a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/8967612).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would match the following :

```
@(.*\.)?somedomain\.com$
```

`somedomain` is guaranteed to be a whole DN path rather than part of one as it either follows the ending `.` of the optional group or the `@` that precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
\w+\.com
```

It will select `.com` and the word preceding it.