# "example@something.com" -> "example" PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm very new to regular expressions and can't really figure out how it works. I have tried this:

```
function change_email($email){
   return preg_match('/^[\w]$/', $email);
}
```

But this only returns a boolean true or false, I want it to return everything BEFORE the @.
Is this possible? I don't even think I use the right php function here..

Comment: an `explode` or `substr` would be better fit here. If you are interested to understand the [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function, php has got one of the [best documentations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in the world. See the sample codes. Matches are available if you use a 3rd parameter in the `preg_match` call.

Comment: E-mail addresses can be more complicated.  While it's unlikely you will encounter one in the wild, remember that an e-mail address may contain more than one `@` symbol.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12355897/362536

Comment: @user3465900 Please accept the answer which helped you. Don't leave answers unaccepted just like that if you got answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a much easier way with [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
explode('@', $email)[0];
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks! Can you try to explain what happens here? What does [0] stand for?

Comment: @user3465900 The explode function returns an array, so [0] returns the first element in that array.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos) to get the position of the `@` character and [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr) to crop out the email:

```
function change_email($email){
    return substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
}
```

**Example:**

```
<?php

function change_email($email){
    return substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
}

var_dump( change_email( 'foo@bar.com' )); // string(3) "foo"
var_dump( change_email( 'example.here@domain.net' )); // string(12) "example.here"
var_dump( change_email( 'not.an.email' )); // string(0) ""
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/168096)

Comment: I like the sanity-check to make sure it has at least the @-sign.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is strstr() function which you can read about [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$email = "name@email.com"
$user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $user; // prints name
```

Answer (score 2):

RegEx

```
.*(?=@)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sO2cD1/1)

```
$re = "/.*(?=@)/"; 
$str = "example@something.com"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a 3rd argument in preg_match which holds the matched items.

Eg:

`preg_match( '/(?P<email_name>[a-zA-Z0-9._]+)@(?P<email_type>\w+)\.\w{2,4}/', $email, $matches );`

```
If $email = 'hello@gmail.com'
$matches['email_name'] will be equal to "hello"
$mathces['email_type'] will be equal to "gmail"
```

Note that email name may only contains letters, numbers, underscore and dot. If you want to add some extra characters add them in the character class --> [a-zA-Z0-9._ other characters ]

Comment: Real e-mail addresses can contain all sorts of stuff... even spaces if  within quotes!

Comment: @Brad as I said, you can add other characters if you want. If you want to allow space you can use [a-zA-Z0-9._\s]. Anyway i dont know any email address with space in it. :)

Comment: Agreed, I'm just throwing the caution out there.  I try to use the Gmail feature of `user+whateveryouwant@gmail.com` all the time, and it often fails because someone's regex is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Through regex,

```
<?php
$mystring = "foo@bar.com";
$regex = '~^([^@]*)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[1]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> foo
```