# How can I split an email address in C# using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an example of an email address like this "mynameismine@hotmail.com", I just want to obtain or cut that string value and obtain this "mynameismine", I dont want to have "@hotmail.com".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newString = emailString.Split('@').First();
```

split the string up by `@`, grab the first item.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the name contained an '@' symbol.

Comment: @Calum if the name contained `@` then it shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: @Calum doubt that would be a valid email address then

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355858/how-many-symbol-can-be-in-an-email-address

Comment: @Calum radical.  you could always grab everything except the last, and concat them together.  However I doubt this is a problem here.

Comment: @Calum I stand corrected. I did not know that such oblivious address (e.g. "this$is#complete.ly@valid-%email"@example.com) is valid.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be manipulating email addresses you're best off using the [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the System.Net.Mail namespace:

```
MailAddress addr = new MailAddress("mynameismine@hotmail.com");
string username = addr.User;
string domain = addr.Host;
```

*username* is the part before the '@' symbol and *domain* is the part after.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try with MailAddress-

Answer (score 2):

[using System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx);

```
MailAddress address = new MailAddress("mynameismine@hotmail.com");
string username = address.User;
```

Just a class specially for these purposes.