# Regular Expressions: Email validation - Ensure single occurrence of @

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation, email

I am using the following regular expression to validate email addresses in my application (Angular 2).

^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$

The validation works fine, however, its failing for email addresses that contain more than one '`@`' symbol (which should be invalid). e.g.

The following emails pass the check (when they should fail):

```
john@subaru@ferrari.com
john@subaruferrari@.com
```

We are looking at modifying this pattern (and not using another pattern as this is in use in production and we do not want excessive changes) so as to accommodate the above use cases.

EDIT: Apologies everybody. Added the regex now.Although the existing answers on SO address pretty much the same situation (validating email addresses), however, I am looking just a quick modification the regex I am using.

Comment: where is the regular expression?

Comment: `I am using the following regular expression` Where?

Comment: What is the regex you are using?

Comment: [How many @ symbol can be in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355858/how-many-symbol-can-be-in-an-email-address) (Spoiler: more than one)

Comment: @D.Simon Updated with regex.

Comment: Just tried the regular expression and it works fine. john@subaru@ferrari.com and john@subaruferrari@.com fail, while normal email-adresses work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in the context of an input field on an Angular Form you could (should?) use the provided built-in validator for email rather specifying your own regex pattern.

See the documentation for [Angular Built-in Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)