# JS regex to get domain name from an email

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the perfect regex that will help me extract the domain name of an email. (ex: `hello@domain.com` should return `domain.com`)

A lot of issue on SO address this problem but none of them treat it perfectly.

Here are the special edge cases that I want to tackle:

1. I don't want to keep subdomains. (ex: `hello@sub.domain.com` should return `domain.com` )
2. Some domain extensions have two dots. (ex: `hello@domain.co.uk` should return `domain.co.uk`)
3. It is possible to include an at (`@`) in your domain name (although most registrar do not allow it). (ex: `hello@dom@in.com` should return `dom@in.com`)

I have tried the following regex but they don't tackle all the edge cases:

- `/(?<=@)\S+\.\S+$/` => Does not handle case **1**
- `/[^.@]*?\.\w{2,}$|[^.@]*?\.com?\.\w{2}$/` => Does not handle case **3**

Comment: *"I don't want to keep subdomains. (ex: `hello@sub.domain.com` should return `domain.com` )"* if you don't want subdomains, it should return `com`

Comment: Your case 3 would be interpreted by an email system as user "hello@dom" on domain "in.com"; multiple @ symbols are allowed in email addresses but the last one is the domain separator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355858/how-many-symbol-can-be-in-an-email-address

Comment: ...actually on rereading I'm realizing it wouldn't be a valid email address at all, unless it were literally `"hello@dom"@in.com` (quotes included)

Comment: You are missing other edge cases, such as `username@123.45.67.89`

Comment: @cid, then i want want to keep the first level domain.