# Contact Form 7: validate email field with more than one address

Tags: contact-form-7, email-validation

I would like to be able to send emails from a CF7 form to more than one recipient using an input field in the form to obtain the email addresses. The problem is that the email field of CF7 only validates a single email address not two separated by comma, which are considered invalid.

I COULD use a text field, but then there is no validation at all of correct email syntax. How could I add a field type "emails" with validation of single or multiple emails?

Comment: why not use a repeater field such as the [Smart-grid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension's table construct. User could add as many validated emails as they wish. (see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcC36e69-eM) on tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a std text field and create your own [validation](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/).  You need to hook the cf7 plugin's validation filter for text fields,

```php
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_vaidated_list_of_emails', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'my_vaidated_list_of_emails', 10, 2 );
function my_vaidated_list_of_emails( $results, $field_tag ) {
    // check this is your field
    if ( 'email_lists' === $field_tag->name && isset( $_POST['email_lists'] ) ) {
        // split the lists into an array of emails
        $emails = explode(  ',', $_POST['email_lists'] );
        $count       = 0;
        foreach ( $emails as $e ) {
            $count++;
            if ( false === filter_var( strtolower( trim($e) ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
                $results->invalidate( $tag, "Email no.{$count} in your list is invalid." );
                break; // from the loop, no need to go any further.
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this, but this should do it.

Edit: changed the code to use the far simpler [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) as suggested by [andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2578037/andrew) in the comments below.

Comment: Good answer, but check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355858/how-many-symbol-can-be-in-an-email-address Don't try to regex validate emails, instead use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: Nice!  Wasn't aware of the filter_var function, what a great discovery...tonight I will go to sleep a little more savvy than yesterday :)

Comment: Thanks. With a few corrections this works fine. Corrections: Replace $tag by $field_tag in the body; Remove the "!" from the condition in the first if statement