# get user name from an E-mail address in php

Tags: php, string, email

In PHP, I have a string like this:

```
$string = "user@domain.com";
```

How do I get the "user" from email address only? Is there any easy way to get the value before `@`?

Comment: Caution: Email addresses may contain more than one "@"...!

Comment: You can see this example with strstr() function  : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php#example-4852

Comment: $email = "youremail@somedomain.com";
$domain_name = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
echo "Domain name is :" . $domain_name;

Comment: @deceze: I don't know who upvoted your caution.
In no real life scenario you'll have to take care of more than one@ in an email address. In my whole life, and I have dealt with millions of mails, I've never seen that.

Comment: @John Unfortunately *in practice* you hardly ever see this, exactly because everyone just accepts just the minimal viable email address syntax. The spec would allow for it, if anybody would actually bother fully supporting it.

Comment: The above solutions are giving username instead of domain name as a result.
I found a solution that helped me in getting domain name from the email, regardless of how many '@' it contains. it always gives you the correct domain name.
function getDomain($email)
  {
    $brokenEmail = explode('@', $email);

    $brokenEmailCount = count($brokenEmail);

    return $brokenEmail[$brokenEmailCount - 1];
  }

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850894/regex-split-email-address/36297137#36297137

Comment: @John - FYI, in my 'real life scenario', I have two email addresses that have two '@' that I use everyday - in fact, they are my primary emails.  I've been using them for at least 20 years.  Guess I've never logged into any place you process emails - but they certainly DO exist and are in common enough use!

Comment: @CFPSupport Let's put it that way: You can easily ban any such e-mail addresses in any tool, shopping cart, website you can think about and the economic impact of this desicion is below noticable margin.  
It's like excluding Windows 3.11 support

Comment: Having an email with two @ symbols is a recipe for problems on the internet. Why on earth would you do that to yourself?

Answer (score 33):

Assuming the email address is valid, this textual approach should work:

```
$prefix = substr($email, 0, strrpos($email, '@'));
```

It takes everything up to (but not including) the last occurrence of `@`. It uses the last occurrence because this email address is valid:

```
"foo\@bar"@iana.org
```

If you haven't validated the string yet, I would advice using a filter function:

```
if (($email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) !== false) {
    // okay, should be valid now
}
```

Comment: @jpro i think the question title was wrong :)

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
$string = "user@domain.com";

$explode = explode("@",$string);

array_pop($explode);

$newstring = join('@', $explode);

echo $newstring;
```

Modified for multiple '@' symbols.

Comment: This is not RFC compliant and may fail if an address contains more than one "@"! Yes, that's *possible* (though not much encountered in practice)!

Comment: This will fail for the address `"Abc\@def"@iana.org` any many others.

Comment: str_getcsv() with a `@` separator, but allowing quotes for mailboxes might be an alternative solution `$explode = str_getcsv($string, '@','"');`

Comment: Edited for multiple @ symbols, though it's probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: Could possibly use array_pop to remove the last element of the array then implode array using @ to return it to a string. May help with addresses with multiple @ symbols.

Comment: Using arrays is quite heavy compared to a simple `strrpos()` and `substr()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$user = implode('@', explode('@', $email, -1));
```

or

```
$user = substr($email, 0, strrpos($mail, '@'));
```

Comment: The first snippet of this unexplained answer may not be reliable for all valid email addresses.  The "username" portion of an email address may contain a `@` if it is wrapped inside of double quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address#:~:text=%22very.unusual.%40.unusual.com%22%40example.com

Answer (score 2):

There’s a nice example in the PHP manual entry for the `strpos()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php#117530

> PHP makes this easy for you. When working with domain portion of email addresses, simply pass the return of strstr() to substr() and start at 1:
>
> `substr(strstr($haystack, '@'), 1);`

Comment: This is virtually a link-only answer.  If that link dies, this answer is of little value to researchers.

Comment: this one returns the domain name and not the user, like the user requested

Comment: This will not work if the address contains more than one `@`.

Comment: This is not always true for all valid email addresses.  The "username" portion of an email address may contain a `@` if it is wrapped inside of double quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address#:~:text=%22very.unusual.%40.unusual.com%22%40example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
strstr($email, '@', true);
```

Comment: This is not always true for all valid email addresses.  The "username" portion of an email address may contain a `@` if it is wrapped inside of double quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address#:~:text=%22very.unusual.%40.unusual.com%22%40example.com  Other answers on this page suitably account for this fringe case.

Comment: `strtok($email, '@')` can also be used for the 99.99999999999% of the emails out there.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form (assuming single '@'), you can follow @Ben Fortune's answer (using explode()).

Otherwise, try this:

```
$email1 = "foo@example.com";
$email2 = "b\@r@example.com";

preg_match_all ("/^(.+)@[^@]+$/", $email1, $e1);
preg_match_all ("/^(.+)@[^@]+$/", $email2, $e2);

echo "Emails: {$e1[1][0]} and {$e2[1][0]}\n";
// Result: Emails: foo and b\@r
```

Comment: This works for multiple @ as well, it's just that regular expressions are not the right tool here :)

Comment: Yah, regular expression might be overkill here. Your answer is simpler. I didn't remember the function [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) existed.