# How to trim the right part of the text and display the results

Tags: php

I have an html code which displays user email from php. However i want to trim this part ***@gmail.com***
And display the left part.

Currently I tried this code which is not working.

```
<p id="p1"><?php
 $str = ""
 echo $str . "<br>";
 echo trim($str,"@gmail.com");
 echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]);
?></p>
```

What is the best way to correct it?

For example the email from php database is **name1@gmail.com**,  i want to remove **@gmail.com**  and display only **name1**

Comment: Why did you tag this with java, javascript, and html?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: `str_replace("@gmail.com", "", $string);` assuming it's always "@gmail.com"

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` is not the best choice. Simply split email by `@`:

```
$expl = explode('@', $str);
echo $expl[0];
```

Comment: How will this look with my code, would you provide full solution on my code

Comment: The comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235986/1213708 suggest that this may not work with every e-mail address.

Comment: Elitte: replace your trim line with my code.

Comment: Do you mean my code will have to look like this: <p id="p1"><?php  $expl = explode('@', $str); echo $expl[0];  echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></p>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355858/how-many-symbol-can-be-in-an-email-address